# How can I use both ActiveState and Strawberry perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

I have ActiveState installed already. Due to the ease in installing LibXML, I installed Strawberry. So at current, I have 2 perl programs, ActiveState and Strawberry. To use Strawberry, I need to remove ActiveState as it is the default of Perl. How could I keep both programs and set Strawberry as default in the classpath?

Comment: 1. Put the bin directory for Strawberry Perl before the directories for ActiveState in your `PATH` environment variable, or 2. create an alias or batch file that invokes the perl version you want. e.g., so you can invoke your script as `asperl myscript.pl` or `sbperl myscript.pl`

Comment: Thanks, cool to have different way to call each

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click on "My Computer".
2. Click on "Properties".
3. Click on "Advanced system settings".
4. Click on "Environment Variables...".
5. Select "Path".
6. Click on the nearest "Edit".
7. Remove ActivePerl's `bin` directory from the "Variable value".
8. Add Strawberry Perl's `bin` directory to the "Variable value".
9. Click "OK".

You may need to reopen existing programs and consoles for them to see the change.

Or simply don't use the default and use the full path to `perl.exe`.